# How can I give a file a name

Tags: java, docker

[I'm using Java Docker API](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) and I'm trying to send my text file to the docker container but the file doesn't appear there. I imagine this happens because the file has no title? How can I give the input stream a title?

```
final String configDir = "C:/teste/configuration.txt";

 File file = new File(configDir);
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
 TarArchiveInputStream tarArchiveInputStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(input,"UTF-8");

 dockerClient.copyArchiveToContainerCmd("1025c61de603")
        .withRemotePath("/tmp/")
        .withTarInputStream(tarArchiveInputStream)
        .exec();
```

EDIT: I Don't get any error in my catch. Seems everything works fine but doesn't create. ***If you know a easy way to send a file to docker container in Java tell me please***

Comment: Don't use a `TarArchiveInputStream` for a text file

Comment: What else do I use??

Comment: I'm completely guessing, but don't you just need to specify a filename in `.withRemotePath("/tmp/")`, like: `.withRemotePath("/tmp/foo.tar")`?

Comment: no. if I do that says path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);` to rename files.